# How to know if an id is root id in google drive V3?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

In Google drive V2 we were able to know it by getting ParentReference object and querying with the method getIsRoot().

In V3 we don't have any ParentReference class if we try to get Parents, and hence don't have any method to know if given Id is root or not.

Answer (score 1):

Every file and folder has a parent **except** root (aka 'My Drive' in English). So if your file metadata tells you that it is a folder, and it has no parents, then by implication it is root. NB See the comment from danielx. Under certain rare circumstances, folders can be orphaned, so an additional test would need to be incorporated.

In pseudo code

`boolean isRoot(File file) {
   return (file.parents.size == 0 
        && file.mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
}`

I looked at the source code of an old version of the library to see the actual implementation of the `getIsRoot()` method. It is exposing the isRoot property of the ParentsReference resource. Therefore you can still access this property by using a v2 REST call, specifically https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents#resource

Having said that, there is no guarantee that in the future, Drive won't have multiple roots (eg. for different domains).

Perhaps the safest approach would be to:-

1. Create an empty file/folder with no parents. By definition, this will be created in root.
2. In the json response which is a file resource, check the parents collection to see the ID of the parent, ie. the ID of root.
3. Store this in an Android preference (cookie, server datastore, etc etc depending on where your app is running), or in AppData.

Comment: This is not true, files and folders can be orphaned https://support.google.com/a/answer/6008339?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

a [file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files) resource contains a list which tells you what a files parents are.  It shouldn't be to hard for you to create your own method which will tell you if its root or not.

> parents[] list    The IDs of the parent folders which contain the file.
>   If not specified as part of a create request, the file will be placed
>   directly in the My Drive folder. Update requests must use the
>   addParents and removeParents parameters to modify the values.

Comment: Method is file.getParents() and returns a List<String> of the id's for the current file object you are using.I already used it. But how will we get to know if the id we got is root or not, as getIsRoot() was an api for this only. For now what I do is, save root Id in a static variable when I get children with param as 'root'.I feel it is a round about and not a viable solution.Isn't there any direct api like V2 for checking if current Id is root or not ???

Comment: getIsRoot() Is a method in the Android SDK it is not a method part of the Google Drive API.  There is a difference. Someone needs to add it to the SDK or you the developer need to create your own method that functions like the one you remember from V2.

Comment: As per my knowledge ,getIsRoot() was a method of ParentReference class that was returned as a list by getParents() method of file resource. And both file and ParentReference class were a part of Google Drive API V2 only.

Comment: As I said neither are part of the Google Drive API v2. They are both part of the Android SDK for Google Drive API v2.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, you will have to [get the root folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#get_the_root_folder) and store its ID to compare with.